# How to get Details of client and server using dynatrace

Tags: api, dynatrace

I am very new to Dynatrace and using trial version of it. I am trying to see how its working with API.

I created a Backend and API to use some service from it

Client <------> API <-------> Backend

```
      [1]          [2]
```

From  `Transactions & services>API>Details` I can get response time for whole round trip time and `Transactions & services>Backend>Details` I get response time of Backend.

Is there a way to get response time of [1]  Client to API  and [2]  API to Backend places separately.

Thanks !!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The "Service Flow" allows to see this, you can get to it via `Transactions & Services > Client > Details > Service Flow`, it shows on the right side "Avg. time spent in called service".

The time between API and actual Backend you will only get if you define a custom service for the Backend so that you have separate services for API and Backend.

See https://www.dynatrace.com/news/blog/simplified-custom-service-setup/ for how to use custom services.